# My application does not appear admob ads

Tags: android

In my application `AdMob` ads do not appear please help and here is my code.
thank you.
code:

```
public class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AdView mAdView;
        public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
            super(view);
            MobileAds.initialize(getContext(),"ca-app-pub-3790716330382724~3051722333");
            mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share log cate details?

Comment: you should follow proper documentation https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Comment: Here is my log detail :                                                                         
There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0                             Failed to load ad: 0                                                                            
Received error HTTP response code: 400                                                      There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

Comment: please help me i was spend time last 3 days

Comment: As per your solution but its does't work give another one